# Is it possible to change the font of every menu option in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I was just curious if there's a way I can have every option in my OptionMenu have a different font?So in my case, each option would have it's respective font. So far all I could find online is just setting all the options to the same font. Here is my code: EDIT: I got it where I can see the correct font only after I click though.

```
# function for font selection 
def selectedFont(name, index, mode):
    #fontLabel = tkinter.Label(top, text = font_clicked.get()).pack()
    global font_path
    if font_clicked.get() == 'Calibri':
        font_path = "C:\Windows\Fonts\calibri.ttf"
        dropDown.config(font = ('Calibri', 12))
        return font_path
    elif (font_clicked.get() == 'Comic Sans'):
        font_path = "C:\Windows\Fonts\comic.ttf"
        dropDown.config(font = ('Comic Sans MS', 12))
        return font_path
    elif (font_clicked.get() == 'Broadway'):
        font_path = "C:\Windows\Fonts\BROADW.ttf"
        dropDown.config(font = ('Broadway', 12))
        return font_path
    elif (font_clicked.get() == 'STENCIL'):
        font_path = "C:\Windows\Fonts\STENCIL.ttf"
        dropDown.config(font = ('Stencil', 12))
        return font_path
    elif (font_clicked.get() == 'Blackadder ITC'):
        font_path = "C:\Windows\Fonts\ITCBLKAD.ttf"
        dropDown.config(font = ('Blackadder ITC', 12))
        return font_path

# options for font selection 

optionsFont = [
    "Calibri",
    "Comic Sans",
    "Broadway",
    "STENCIL",
    "Blackadder ITC"
]

#### drop down menu ####

font_clicked = tkinter.StringVar()
font_clicked.set(optionsFont[0])


dropDown = tkinter.OptionMenu(top, font_clicked, *optionsFont)
dropDown["menu"].config(bg="light pink", fg="black")
dropDown.config(bg = "gray81")
dropDown.pack()
dropDown.place(x=50,y=108, height = 30, width = 250)

Callbackname = font_clicked.trace_variable('w', selectedFont)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the font of each item in an option menu but make sure that font is compatible with Tkinter otherwise it won't show up, you can check all the fonts compatible with Tkinter by

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font

root = tk.Tk()
print(list(font.families()))
```

---

Now to change each font in the *optionmenu* we use `entryconfigure` method of the menu linked with the *optionmenu* widget can be accessed by its object (`op['menu']`). The menu of *optionmenu*  has all the [options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.config-method) of a Tkinter Menu.

*Take a look at this example.*

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x150')
var = tk.StringVar()

op = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *font.families())
op.pack(pady=20)

lb = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)
lb.pack()

for item in range(0, int(op['menu'].index('end'))):
    op['menu'].entryconfig(item, font=font.Font(family=font.families()[item]))

var.trace('w', lambda *a: lb.config(font=op['menu'].entrycget(var.get(),'font')))
root.mainloop()
```